# Navigation Bar Links not working in iOS and Android

Tags: android, html, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that i have programmed. everything works from Internet Explorer and Chrome/Firefox from a computer. but if you go to an Android or IOS Device my navigation menu does not work on the sub menu's

I have tested the site using chrome device emulator debug and everything works there.

But when i try on my phone using IE or Chrome the submenu Links are not clickable

In this image the Links with yellow boxes work however the links in the submenus do not "only when actually on Android / IOS Devices

[image: Navigation Bar]

here is my relevant coding:

css:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 50px; }

@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png');
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;
@heroUnitHeadingColor: @white;
@heroUnitLeadColor: @white;
@navbarBackground: #122040;
@navbarBackgroundHighlight: #223D7A;
@navbarHeight: 40px;
@navbarLinkColor: @white;
@navbarLinkColorHover: yellow;
@navbarLinkColorActive: @navbarLinkColorHover;
@navbarLinkBackgroundActive: transparent;
@shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
.navbar .nav > li > a {
  font-size:17px;
}

.black{
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: bold
}
.well{
  background: #e6e6e6;
  -moz-box-shadow:    @shadow;
  -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
  box-shadow:         @shadow;
}

.navbar .nav .pull-left{
  left: 1%;
  float:none;
}

//.icon-pencil::before,.icon-exclamation-sign::before,.icon-file::before,.icon-search::before,.icon-thumbs-up::before,.icon-book::before,.icon-briefcase::before,.icon-question-sign::before,.icon-comment::before,.icon-chevron-right::before, .icon-home::before, .icon-user::before,{
    //content: "";
//}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .span12, .container {
    width: 1375px;
    padding: none;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container-fluid
      %a.btn.btn-navbar{"data-toggle"=>"collapse","data-target"=>".nav-collapse"}
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
      .nav.pull-left
        %a.nav.loadmaxlogo{:href => "/"}
          %img{:src=>"/assets/loadmax_logo2.png", alt: "#1 Loadboard on the net."}
      .nav-collapse.collapse
        -if user_signed_in?
          %ul.nav
            %li
              %a{:href => "/"}
                %i.icon-home.icon-white 
                Home
          %ul.nav
            %li.dropdown
              %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle"=>"dropdown", :href=>"#"}
                Search
                %i.caret
              %ul.dropdown-menu
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/searches/new?search_type=ezsearch"}
                    EZ Search
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/searches/new"}
                    Advanced Search
                -if current_user.account_manager? || current_user.admin?
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/find_user"}
                      User Search
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/containers"}
                      Add Container Notifiers
          %ul.nav
            %li.dropdown
              %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle"=>"dropdown", :href=>"#"}
                Post
                %i.caret
              %ul.dropdown-menu.no-collapse
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/loads/new"} Post a Load
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/loads/post_many"} Post Many Loads
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/trucks/new"} Post a Truck
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/trucks/post_many"} Post Many Trucks
          %ul.nav
            %li.dropdown
              %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle"=>"dropdown", :href=>"#"}
                Help
                %i.caret
              %ul.dropdown-menu.no-collapse
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/info/help"} How to Autopost
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/info/help#post"} How to Post
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/info/help#search"} How to Search
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/info/help#equipmentguide"} Equipment Guide
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/info/help#faq"} FAQ
                %li
                  %a{:href => "/info/help#termsofservice"} Terms of Service
            %li
              %a{:href => "/info/contact"} Contact Us
          .nav.pull-right
            %ul.nav
              %li.dropdown.pull-right
                %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle"=>"dropdown", :href=>"#"}
                  %i.icon-user.icon-white
                  My Account
                  %i.caret
                %ul.dropdown-menu.no-collapse
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/users/#{current_user.id}/posts"} My Posts
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/users/#{current_user.id}/covered"} Covered Posts
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/users/leads"} Saved Posts
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/users/#{current_user.id}/edit"} Account Preferences
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/notifications"} Notifiers
                  %li
                    %a{:href => "/documents/#{current_user.id}"} My Documents
                  -if (current_user.company_manager && current_user.normal?) || current_user.account_manager?  || current_user.admin?
                    %li
                      %a{:href => edit_payment_info_path(current_user.company.id)} Update Payment Info
                  -if current_user.admin? or current_user.account_manager?
                    %li
                      %a{:href => "/testimonials"} Testimonials
                  -if (current_user.company_manager && current_user.free?) || current_user.account_manager? || current_user.admin?
                    %li
                      %a{:href => "/subscription_upgrades/#{current_user.company.id}/edit"} Upgrade Subscription

            %li.divider-vertical
            %li
              =link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
        -else
          .nav.pull-left
            %ul.nav
              %li
                %a{:href => "/"}
                  %i.icon-home.icon-white
                  Home
            %li
              %a{:href => "/features/show"} Features
            %li
              %a{:href => "/info/contact"} Contact Us
          .nav.pull-right
            %li
              %a{:href => "/users/sign_up"}
                %i.icon-user.icon-white
                Sign Up
            %li.divider-vertical
            %li
              =link_to "Login", new_user_session_path
```